# After replacing Scene, the Schedule method doesn't work anymore

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm making a game in cocos2dx , so I've made a class named `CoCoGui`
and I've also made an `IntroPage` class that inherits from `CCLayerColor` for the intro page of the game and a `StartPage` class that's been inherited from `CCLayerColor`, too.
I want to show the intro page for the first 2 seconds and then show the `StartingPage` 
but in the `updateGame` function of `CoCoGui` (which is the main loop of the game), when the `replaceScene` method called, and the `Scene` become replaced, the `updateGame` method won't be called anymore!
Please help me with this problem
thanks!

Here's the CoCoGui.h file:
`StartingPage` and `IntroPage` are two classes that inherit from `CCLayerColor`

```
#ifndef _COCOGUI_H_
#define _COCOGUI_H_

#include "StartingPage.h"
#include "..\Classes\WorkSpace.h"
#include "..\Classes\GameBoard.h"
#include "..\Classes\IntroPage.h"
using namespace cocos2d;

class CoCoGui : public CCLayerColor{

public:
    CoCoGui();
    void addScene (CCScene * startPage, CCScene * work);
    virtual ~CoCoGui(void);
    void updateGame ( float dt );
    virtual bool init();
    static CCScene* scene();
    CREATE_FUNC(CoCoGui);
private:
    bool isInit;
    CCScene * runnigScene;
    IntroPage * introPage;
    StartingPage * startingPage;
    void onEnterTransitionDidFinish();
    void menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender);
public:
    CCScene * getRunningScene(void);
};

#endif /* COCOGUI_H */
```

also here is CoCoGui.cpp file

```
#include "CoCoGui.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
CCScene* CoCoGui::scene(){
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();
    CoCoGui *layer = CoCoGui::create();

    scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}

CoCoGui::CoCoGui ( )
{
    this->isInit = false;
    this->introPage = new IntroPage ( );
    this->startingPage = new StartingPage ( );
}

CoCoGui::~CoCoGui(void)
{
    delete introPage;
    delete startingPage;
}

void CoCoGui::menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender)
{
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    exit(0);
#endif
}

bool CoCoGui::init ( ){
    if ( !CCLayerColor::initWithColor ( ccc4 (100,100,100,255) ) ){
        return false;
}
    this->schedule ( schedule_selector ( CoCoGui::updateGame ), 0.5 );
    return true;
}

void CoCoGui::updateGame ( float dt ){
    cout << "Update Called" << endl;
    if ( !isInit )
        return;
    CCScene * scene = NULL;
    if ( !this->introPage->isIntroPageDone ( ) ){
        scene = IntroPage::scene();
    }
    else if ( this->introPage->isIntroPageDone ( )  ){
        scene = StartingPage::scene();
}
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(scene);
}

void CoCoGui::onEnterTransitionDidFinish ( ){
    isInit = true;
}


CCScene * CoCoGui::getRunningScene(void)
{
    return this->runnigScene;
}
```

Comment: try to understand how cocos2d handle CCScene, CCLayer and node by CCDirector first before starting programming. Make sure you know when you start a Scene, which default functions been called before you enter the scene and which functions been called after you leave that scene. there are 2 books really good: Cocos2d for iphone Game Development Cookbook / Learn cocos2d Game Development with iOS 5. cocos2d-x using the same way as cocos2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is anything like cocos2d-iphone, you'll have to call the base class implementation of onEnterTransitionDidFinish and similar onEnter/onExit overrides. In cocos2d-iphone not calling super in some of these methods can cause scheduling and input to stop working.

Comment: So, could you bring me an example to do that? I'm a bit beginner with cocos2dx and I don't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

the ReplaceScene will trigger the `this->onExit()` which will trigger `unschedule` function.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
this->resume();
```

after calling the schedule.

Also make sure that the scene connected to the layer is loaded.  If not, it will cause a runtime error.